# Overlapping Multi Day events into a single line instead of stacked in Fullcalendar.io

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

[image: How it looks now.]

[image: How I would like it to look.]

I am pulling a ICal Feeds into Fullcalendar.io. For events where their dates overlap they are stacked (see first image). I would actually like them to appear on one line (see second image).

What would be the appropriate way to do this? I actually have multiple sources i'm pulling from with different color bars, so it would be cleaner if I could get the overlapping events from the same source on one line.

Thanks.

Comment: From a UX point of view, wouldn't that be confusing? For instance, by looking at your second image, I'd imagine the first event ends on Tuesday and that is not the case...
UI/UX aside, I would look into content injection hooks on Fullcalendar. Although I think this is quite a difficult task you're aiming to achieve.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks

Comment: @clesmalo Yes. You are right. And actually playing around with eventOrder and looking at it more it makes more sense as is. Thanks for your feedback.